# ReportViewer.ServerReport.Render("Excel") ignoring conditional formatting in report?

Tags: excel, ssrs-2012

I have reports which I'd like to render to excel using just a link. In order to do this, I have a page (web application, actually) which uses the ReportViewer to select the parameters and then intercepts the rendering phase. I then execute the rendering as an excel render using `byte[] result = ReportViewer.ServerReport.Render("Excel");` and sending this to the user.

I got it working, but there's a quirk: The excel files are generated with the headers still in place. The reports define these to not to be rendered when rendering to excel, as the tab names already contain the names and they interfere with one click pivoting.

I've looked through the interface of the reportviewer form, but I can't seen to be able to find anything which would trigger the conditional formatting. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the expression in your conditional formatting refers to "EXCELOPENXML" rather than "EXCEL" if you are exporting to .xlsx format.  Or you may need to pass this value to the Render function.  Or both.  If you are exporting to a version of Excel earlier than 2007, this will not apply.

These two format types differ in how they are encoded.  My understanding is that an SSRS report rendered as type 'EXCEL' is encoded in binary, whereas those of type 'EXCELOPENXML' are, naturally, encoded in XML.

This is purely speculation, but the visibility expression may expect a specific type of encoding based on the version of Excel you are using. So even though either might render to the application, only one evaluates the expression as you expect.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. My question is not about the file format, it's about the visibility expressions present in the report not being executed. AFAIK the file format (xls/xlsx) shouldn't make a difference. Are you saying it it?

Comment: What expression is used in the rdl to set the visibility property?  It sounds like you would be using something like =Globals!RenderFormat.Name="EXCEL".  My point is that this will evaluate to FALSE if the file format is .xlsx and TRUE if it is .xls.  You could use =Globals!RenderFormat LIKE "EXCEL*" to evaluate to TRUE in both versions, or use =Globals!RenderFormat ="EXCELOPENXML" to have it hide only for .xlsx.  I'm less familiar with the Render function, but this naming convention may apply there as well, which was the last point I was trying to make.

Comment: The expression defining the visibility is =IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name like "EXCEL*",true,false)
To me it really seems that there's a problem with the renderer ignoring the  format.

Comment: Just for kicks, can you change the parameter in your Render function from "EXCEL" to "EXCELOPENXML"?  Also, it shouldn't impact the result but IIF(...,true,false) seems redundant, no?

Comment: It actually solved the issue somehow. I don't get it. The expression should match excel as well. if you can explain why this works/might work in your answer, I'll mark it as my pick. Thnx for the help :)

Comment: I don't know exactly what's happening under the hood, but I've added some info to my answer.